# What does the phrase "come in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This is a scene from the movie "The Shining" by Stanley Kubrick(video link below)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVoLTp46nP8

> WENDY: And you're gonna lose.  And I'm gonna get you - you betta run fast! Look out - I'm **coming in** close. All right?

**"come in"**

3. To finish a contest or competition in a particular position or place (as in first, second, third, etc.).
   *I didn't expect to come in first or anything, but finishing last is pretty disappointing.*(source: Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)

**This definition doesn't make sense though because she is still chasing him and the race isn't over.**

Comment: Approaching closely, or following close behind.

Answer (score 4):

The phrasal verb "come in" has many meanings. Look at the list in the definitions by:

- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/come-in)
- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/come-in)
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20in)
- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/come-in)
- [Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/come-in)

Oxford Learner's gives as one meaning:

> to arrive somewhere; to be received: *The train is coming in now.*

Somewhat related to this is *The tide is coming in*, meaning that the water is covering the shore.

Another meaning is to land or approach for landing in an airplane:  *The pilot is coming in at a steep angle.* This and similar uses have been generalized into a meaning of "approach". This or something near it, is the meaning in your example.

Comment: David@ I searched through all these dictionaries except Oxford Learner's before writing this post and these are my staple everyday glossaries I use. I referred to these once more plus to the one you added and there is no definition with the meaning "approach" although there is  "arrive" but I'm pretty sure if I saw "approach" before posting I wouldn't have probably done it.

Comment: @Static Bounce You are correct, the "approach" meaning isn't in any of thoise, although the meaning of the tide is somewhat similar, as is the meaning of enter. I know the approach meaning through having heard it used. It is also in a comment by   Michael Harvey,  endorsed by 5 other users. I wonder why you selected the "place in a contest" meaning to quote in the question as **the** definition? Also, FYI, to alert another user the at-sign must go **before** the user name, not after it. But I was notified anyway, because this is a comment on an answer I posted.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm a newbie when it comes to forums:) I selected "place in a contest" because I knew this definition for this phrase and it was the closest thing relating to two people racing. OFC I suspected what the meaning was from the context but I couldn't find a definition for it anywhere so I decided to post here because I learned in the past that it's important to confirm as context can be misleading and after learning the missing word it actually changes the sentence quiet dramatically:)

Comment: @Static It was fine to post as you did. I am only asking questions to understand how to help. In such a situation  it would be helpful to mention you consulted several online dictionary sites, perhaps naming a few, and that the def you quoted was the closest you could find. Also when you quote a def, or an example sentence, please identify the source & give proper credit, as you very helpfully did for the excerpt from *The Shining*. For a lot mote info about ELL, see the [*Contributor's Guide*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an instance of the phrasal verb *come in* at all. I think it's *I'm coming* with an adverbial *in close*.

**Edit**: I don't think I was quite right. I think it is *[coming in] close*, where *coming in* isn't a "phrasal verb" with a special meaning, just a verb with an adverb specifying where; then "close" is a further adverb that says how far.

Comment: Hmm, ok, but I can't find any definition for an "adverbial in close". Can you provide it?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: If "in" is an adverb specifying "where" is this the correct definition for it: **(2. To or toward a destination or goal: The mob closed in.<source:American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language>)**? If not, can you provide a definition?